# Facets not properly getting indexed in elasticsearch using tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am  trying to implement facets based on the example in

http://railscasts.com/episodes/307-elasticsearch-part-2

I created a table with state_id and state_name. I created facets in model file as follows

```
facet "univ" do 
        terms :state_id, size: 50
end
```

and my view is

```
<ul>
<% @univ.facets['univ']['terms'].each do |facet| %>
<li class="nav-header">
<%= link_to_unless_current Univ.find(facet['term']).state, params.merge(state_id: facet['term']) %> 
<%if params[:state_id] == facet['term'].to_s %>
(<%= link_to "remove", state_id: nil%>)
<%else%>
(<%= facet['count']%>)
<%end%>
</li>
<%end%>
</ul>
```

for some reason my 8th state_id doesn't get indexed and when I add a 9th state_id id the details of 8th state_id are shown in the facet link. In the following figure on clicking MA(1) returns values for state PA and PA(1) returns the results for next indexed state_id which is NC

[image]